# Converting an example jQuery function to vanilla JS: apparent trouble with Element.offsetTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not even sure exactly what I'm asking, so bear with me.

I'm trying to replicate the effect in [this](https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz) cool pen from [Krz Szzz](https://codepen.io/ccrch)

Here's the original jQuery:

```
   $('.tile')
    // tile mouse actions
     .on('mouseover', function(){
      $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data- 
   scale') +')'});
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
      $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale(1)'});
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
    $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - 
    $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - 
    $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
    })
```

And [here's](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOvXWj) my attempt to nativize the jQuery (I've tried to reduce the complexity to focus on the issue at hand, so my markup is a bit different than his/hers, but not in relevant ways, I don't believe).

```
var tile = document.querySelector('.tile');
var tileWidth = tile.offsetWidth;
var tileHeight = tile.offsetHeight;
var tileTop = tile.offsetTop;
var tileLeft = tile.offsetLeft;

tile.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  tile.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
});

tile.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  tile.style.transformOrigin = ((e.pageX - tileLeft) / tileWidth) * 100 + "%" + ((e.pageY - tileTop) / tileHeight) * 100 + "%";
});

tile.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  tile.style.transform = "scale(1)";
});
```

My version halfway works. But there's a calculation error somewhere in there that prevents setting the correct value for the second parameter of the `transform-origin` CSS.

I *believe* the issue has to do with `$(this).offset().top` in the jQuery. I've converted this to `Element.offsetTop`, but that may not be correct. I've burned 1.5 hours trying to learn my way to success here on SO, but I'm not making any headway.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `offset().top()` gets coords related to the **document** while js `offsetTop` is related to the **parentNode**.

You may give `Element.getBoundingClientRect().top` a try.

It'll give you the top position related to the **viewport**, not to the **document**. But it's a beginning.

Then, you can get the scroll position with `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and sum both of them.

---

PS: `document.documentElement.scrollTop` doesn't work on Safari, as I'm concerned. Use `document.body.scrollTop` instead.

Comment: Nice! That sorted things for me. I also needed to use `Element.getBoundingClientRect().left` rather than `Element.offsetLeft`. Thanks a million!

Updated pen here: https://codepen.io/metafisk/pen/XOvXWj